# Can Firebase Queries get items by count/offset?

Tags: android, ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Is there a way in Firebase we can specify query by count.

For Example if the total number of records under the node are 100 and I don't want to retrieve 100 in just one query. Can I say return me first 10 and then next 10 and so on.

I know Firebase provides queries like limitToFirst() and limitToLast() but then it won't address the use case defined above.

Please let me know if anyone has any thoughts on this.

Comment: Can you share a use example?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28558586/angularjs-fetch-records-for-pagination-from-firebase

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue and unfortunately firebase doesn't allow to do that. The only way you can handle this is to retrieve all data you need and then order it on client side.

Example:

```
private void getData() {
    List<ModelType> data;
    fireBaseRef = new Firebase(FIREBASE_PATH);
    Query query = fireBaseRef.child(PATH).orderByChild(CHILD_NAME_PATH);

    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            data = new ArrayList<>();
            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                ModelType model = snapshot.getValue(ModelType.class);
                data.add(model);
                // ..
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```