# Firebase get all values of specific key

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a `users` *table* on Firebase and each user has an `email` prop.

Structure looks like:

`Users` -> `User UID` (looks like `n8haBbjgablobA2ranfuabu3aaaga2af`) -> `User Obj` which includes `email` prop.

I'd like to get an array of all the users' emails (~1m).

How can I most efficiently do this?

Ps.:

I tried:

```
usersRef.startAt(0).endAt(20).once("value", function(snapshot) {
  console.log('FIRST 20');
  console.log(snapshot.val()); // null
});
```

But that fails.

Comment: It's pretty simple to iterate over all of the user nodes using childAdded events (so only one loads at a time). But the bigger question is why are you doing this? There are probably much better ways to do it than load them all in at once but we would need to understand your use case.

Comment: I am starting a newsletter on my website and I need to gather all current emails. It's a one-time thing to get started, as emails from new sign ups will be added as the user signs up.

Comment: If the querying is fine, I'll keep all data in the Firebase and every time I send a newsletter, I query + send in chunks.

Comment: Seems like nobody actually knows how to get this done. A lot of work needs to be done at Firebase for it to be a viable database solution for large sites (and 1m users isn't really large). I came up with a solution anyhow, a weird one but working one.

Comment: Actually, my comment was a super easy and straight forward answer. Iterate over all your data with childAdded. It will take a while but it would take all of about 10 lines of code.

Comment: How do you use child_added to get chunks of data though? Could you provide an actual answer using this technique?

Comment: You can go for the chunky route or just iterate over all the nodes and append them to a file as they are read in. See my answer. I am not a java guy but the process presented is sound.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the most efficient approach in terms of data reads would be to denormalize your data.  You could store the email addresses both in the individual user nodes and in an `emailAddresses` node.  Then you could just query the `emailAddresses` node directly for your list of emails.

Still ~1m email address nodes would probably be too much all at once.  I'd probably grab it in chunks... I'm guessing.

### Update

"Grabbing in chunks" is essentially pagination.  I would try to use something off the shelf before trying to roll my own pagination solution.

Pagination libraries to check out:

- [Firebase Utils Pagination](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-util/tree/master/src/Paginate): This is developed by Firebase, but they say it is experimental and not ready for production use.  But, it's probably still worth messing around with.
- [firebase-paginator](https://github.com/deltaepsilon/firebase-paginator): this is developed by a community member and it seems pretty solid.

If you want to roll your own pagination, check out:

- @kato's response in [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28558586/angularjs-fetch-records-for-pagination-from-firebase)  He makes an interesting point about the potential problem with paginating a real time data set, but then provides some good starter code
- [Here's a good blog entry](https://howtofirebase.com/firebase-data-structures-pagination-96c16ffdb5ca#.k0vbhg3b5) that talks about the code that I think is a part of the firebase-paginator library I linked to above

Comment: How do you grab it in chunks?

Answer (score 0):

Everybody in their answers said that it was an easy thing, yet had no working solutions. Here's what I came up with:

```
usersRef.orderByChild('uid').limitToFirst(100).once('value', function (snapshot) {
  var users = snapshot.val()
  var uids = Object.keys(users);
  var lastUid = uids[uids.length - 1];

  // could be another property than uid, for example email, or username. Ps.: Consider that the last ID from the previous chunk will be duplicated.
  usersRef.orderByChild('uid').startAt(lastUid).limitToFirst(100).once('value', function (snapshot) {
    var users = snapshot.val()
    var uids = Object.keys(users);
    console.log(uids);
    var lastUid = uids[uids.length - 1];
    // re-run function until done
  })
})
```

Comment: If your paging uses `orderByChild`, I think your first query should, too: `usersRef.orderByChild('uid').limitToFirst(100)`. (At the moment, it won't matter as the key and child ordering will be the same, but if you use a child like `email` - as per your comment - the orderings between the first and subsequent queries will differ.)

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a one-time deal, an option is to simply iterate over each node in the parent 'data' node capturing the child data, stripping out the email address and dumping that to a file.

the event you want is

> child_added: retrieve lists of items or listen for additions to a list
>   of items. This event is triggered once for each existing child and
>   then again every time a new child is added to the specified path. The
>   listener is passed a snapshot containing the new child's data.

and the code to iterate all of the child nodes in the data node is

```
var dataRef = firebase.database().ref('myRootRef/data');
datRef.on('child_added', function(data) {
  //data.val() will contain the child data, such as the email address
  //append it to a text file here (for example), save to disk etc.
});
```

The key here is that this event is triggered once for each child, similar to iterating over all of the indexes in an array.

This will retrieve each child and present it to your app, one child at a time, iterating over all the children within the node.

It's going to take a while with that many nodes to chew through.