# How to limit data in firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to implement Pagination in my site, so what i want is to limit the incoming data from firebase to 10 ads per page.

[image: Data Structure]

this is how the data is structured, every ad has it's own unique key, so i want to retrieve 10 ads per page.

```
function fetchAds(cat) {
    database.ref("ads/console").startAt(10).endAt(20).on('value', function(snapshot) {
        (() => {

            console.log(snapshot.val())

    })();
    });
}
```

This is how i'm trying to do, but i know it's not going to work because `startAt()` and `endAt()` needs to be with `orderBy`, and i don't wan't to pass the keys to `startAt()` and `endAt()` because these ads can be deleted so if i have specified a key of an ad in the `startAt()` and that key get deleted the pagination will fail.

Comment: For each page, request eleven elements (using `limitToFirst(11)`), but only display ten of them on screen.  Then use the key of the eleventh element as the `startAt()` key for the next page.

Comment: The pagination won't fail if you use `startAt()`. According to the documentation, `startAt()` "Return items greater than or equal to the specified key or value, depending on the order-by method chosen." As in, if the given key isn't present, it will start at the next key.

Comment: Firebase's query mechanism is not limit/offset based. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28558586/angularjs-fetch-records-for-pagination-from-firebase

Comment: Daniel Beck, your solution will work, but then i have to manually pass the keys on every page number, and these keys are randomly generated keys.